# Google maps embed with wrong zoom

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-embed

i'm having a problem with new google maps embed.
As you can see in my print off my site, the maps embed is so far zoomed out.
How can i solve this problem ? I want to embed the map with a regular/normal zoom

I can't add image to this post because i don't have the necessary reputation.
Here's a link of my print: http://imageshack.com/a/img89/958/figs.jpg

Thanks guys!

Comment: Please add the javascript code you are using to generate the map.

Comment: i'm using the html iframe:
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d3691.5217809275764!2d-48.55680935!3d-22.296098!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x94c7580226334421%3A0xc3000e7281a1ebdb!2sRua+Louren%C3%A7o+Prado%2C+218+-+Centro!5e0!3m2!1spt-BR!2sbr!4v1394721710945" width="400" height="300" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>

Answer (score 5):

You can add a zoom paramater to the src part of your html code. The lower the number the farther out you zoom. Zoom = 10 is a good place to start testing.

```
<iframe width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=API_KEY&q=Space+Needle,Seattle+WA&zoom=10"></iframe>
```

You can find out more in Google's documentation on this page under "Optional Parameters".
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide

Answer (score 0):

Use `<embed>[…]</embed>` instead of `<iframe>[…]</iframe>`.

`<embed src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d3691.5217809275764!2d-48.55680935!3d-22.296098!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x94c7580226334421%3A0xc3000e7281a1ebdb!2sRua+Louren%C3%A7o+Prado%2C+218+-+Centro!5e0!3m2!1spt-BR!2sbr!4v1394721710945%22; width="400" height="300" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></embed>`

Source: https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/maps/kcjwmB5XFx8/qjR9DyAFPDwJ

Answer (score 0):

All you do is in the url after your coordinates or place of interested you add &zoom=n (n being the zoom level)