# Google Maps Embed API for directions - zoom to fit origin and destination

Tags: zooming, directions, google-maps-embed

The Google Maps **[Embed API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/)** for [directions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide#directions) doesn't always show the origin and destination in the frame. Sometimes the default zoom level is zoomed-in too much.

```
<iframe 
    src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/directions?     
        origin=%2020858%20King%20Hezekiah%20Way%20%20Bend%20Oregon%20United%20States&amp;
        destination=1180%20SE%203rd%20Street%2C%20Bend%2C%20OR&amp;
        key=******************************" 
    width="281" 
    height="370">
</iframe>
```

*(Whitespace added for readability.)*

[image: example embed directions zoomed in too far, by default]

Almost solutions:

- for JavaScript API version 3, using map.fitBounds(), https://stackoverflow.com/a/19304625/673991
- for JavaScript API, using map.getBoundsZoomLevel(), https://stackoverflow.com/a/2362436/673991
- with explicit zoom, https://stackoverflow.com/a/23300810/673991  (The explicit `zoom` parameter is not a general solution because it's impossible to know the correct value. In this example it would be `zoom=14`.)

Here's how it should look (e.g. with `zoom=14` or <kbd>-</kbd> manual zoom-out):

[image]

Here is a **[live example](https://www.brushoff.com/static/example/wrong_zoom.html)**.

Are there any solutions or workarounds within the Embed API?  Is this a [bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64411165)?

**UPDATE** in February 2018 this appears to have been fixed. That is, on the [live example](https://www.brushoff.com/static/example/wrong_zoom.html) the Bad Map now looks the same as the workaround. Guess that's better than an answer or a mea culpa.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="height: 400px">
  <iframe width="100%" height="100%" 
    src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/directions?     
    origin=%2020858%20King%20Hezekiah%20Way%20%20Bend%20Oregon%20United%20States&amp;
    destination=1180%20SE%203rd%20Street%2C%20Bend%2C%20OR&amp;
    key=******************************"  allowfullscreen>
  </iframe>
</div>
```

you can try like this. Just set fixed width and height to div not to iframe

Comment: Thanks, a valid thing to try, setting the iframe to fill an outer div. But alas I can't try it because Google seems to have fixed it. (And I just today fixed my links to the live example, which were broken.)